# What method should I use to replace text within a String

Tags: java, string, replace

I have the following string:

```
str = "kishore kumar venkata"
```

I want to replace this string with "kishore tamire venkata".

What are the string methods used for this? Can someone explain the procedure for replacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method to use is (hardly surprising) [`String.replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
str = str.replace("kumar", "tamire");
```

Note that as `String` is immutable, the original string is not changed, and the method returns the modified string instead.

Answer (score 1):

For simple replacements, you can use `String.replace(...)`, as Péter already suggested. However, be aware that replace(...) also causes the substring `kumar` to be replaced in the string:

```
"kishore kumaraa venkata"
         ^^^^^
```

if you *don't* want that to happen, you could use the `String.replaceAll(...)` and provide the regex pattern:

```
\bkumar\b
```

where `\b` denotes a word boundary.

A demo:

```
String str = "kishore kumaraa kumar venkata";
String rep = str.replaceAll("\\bkumar\\b", "tamire");
System.out.println(str+"\n"+rep);
```

will print:

```
kishore kumaraa kumar venkata
kishore kumaraa tamire venkata
```